# DJANGO Data update problem. No Error Code

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to update the data I have determined in the database by pulling it with post. However, it is not updated. The codes in the view.py file are also added. It may work for the application.

views.py

```
    def bilgilerim(request,id):
    bilgilerim_cek=players.objects.get(user_id=id)
   context={
        'bilgiler': bilgilerim_cek,
        'leaguelist': leagues.objects.all(),
        'players': players.objects.filter(user_id=id),
    }
    return render(request,'profil/bilgilerim.html', context)

    def bilgilerim_guncel(request):
        
            if(request.method=='POST'):
                name_surname= request.POST['name_surname']
                mobile_number= request.POST['mobile_number']
                age= request.POST['age']
                length= request.POST['length']
                weight= request.POST['weight']
                foot= request.POST['foot']
                position= request.POST['position']
                players.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(name_surname=name_surname,mobile_number=mobile_number,age=age,foot=foot,length=length,position=position,weight=weight)
        
            return render(request, 'profil/bilgilerim.html')
```

players_models.py

```
class players(models.Model):
    name_surname=models.CharField(max_length=18,null=False,blank=False)
    mobile_number=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    player_status=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    team_id=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    photo=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='resim-yok.jpg')
    awards=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    dogecoin=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    age=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    foot=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,blank=False)
    length=models.CharField(max_length=4,null=False,blank=False)
    weight=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    red_card=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    position=models.CharField(max_length=2,null=False,blank=False)
    form_points=models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

bilgilerim.html  Below is the form structure that I have POST.

```
<form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal fade" id="namesurname" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" name="name_surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Ad ve Soyad" value="{{ bilgilerim_x.name_surname }}" aria-label="Ad ve Soyad" style="font-size:20px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Güncelle</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: If you make an update it will update *all* `Players`, so not a single one, but *all* records.

Comment: Can you share the form part of the template where you call this view?

Comment: You're not actually setting `user_id` anywhere, so you're never going to find any records! Also, you haven't specifically set your pk to `user_id`, so it's actually going to be called `id`

Comment: There are many form structures. I can't add them all. However, they all look alike. I added one. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Actually there is. Just Froeign key `user_id` @michjnich

Comment: You're setting `user_id=user_id` , but there's no value for that second `user_id`. Also, accessing the values of a FK needs a double underscore, so it would be `user__id=user_id` (still missing that `user_id` value though).

Comment: Do you want to update information of current user or based on the user id *(anyone)*?

Comment: I want to update based on current user's information. This is actually a profile page. The user's information is written on the screen. 

Example. My username is Alex, when I click on the text Alex, the form opens and Alex appears as the value value. I am changing this and posting it. And I want it to be updated in the database.
@Arjun

Comment: I can't help feeling you're misunderstanding a whole lot of what Django offers. Might I suggest you run through the django girls tutorial. FOr me, it's the best one out there: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/

Comment: I've already completed that training. thank you @michjnich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your queryset is empty with `players.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)` and I can't see any  *second* `user_id` value here in your view.

If you are trying to update the information of current user you can do this.

```
players.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(..)
```

`request.user` will return the currently logged in User's instance.

Also it's better to use django [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) if you have so many fields to update with.

Comment: `players.objects.filter(user=request.user)` please check what this will return ?

Comment: I checked. But still the same. Database not updating

Comment: I mean print out this queryset in your view or in shell. `print(players.objects.filter(user=request.user))` ,check what this will print ?

Comment: `>>> print(players.objects.filter(user=request.user))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'players' is not defined`

Comment: Did you import players in shell before print the previous code? Also, it is a good practice to make model name with the first letter uppercase and singular, rather than plural.